# Convert URL language as website language changes

Tags: url, url-rewriting, internationalization, multilingual

How can we convert language of URL as website language changes?

Like take example of `www.example.com/test` it is in English. When I am changing website language to Persian it should be `www.example.com/آزمون`.

Is it possible? How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PHP, this may help. You can change the `language` as you wish, depending on what language you want your website to be in.

`/*
-----------------`

`Language: German`

`-----------------`
*/
    `$lang = array();
    $lang['PAGE_TITLE'] = 'Meine Webseite Titel';
    $lang['HEADER_TITLE'] = 'Meine Website-Header Titel';
    $lang['SITE_NAME'] = 'Meine Website';
    $lang['SLOGAN'] = 'Mein Slogan hier';
    $lang['HEADING'] = 'Position';`

`// Menu`
 `$lang['MENU_HOME'] = 'Heim';
    $lang['MENU_ABOUT_US'] = 'Über uns';
    $lang['MENU_OUR_PRODUCTS'] = 'Unsere Produkte';
    $lang['MENU_CONTACT_US'] = 'Kontaktieren Sie uns';
    $lang['MENU_ADVERTISE'] = 'Werben';
    $lang['MENU_SITE_MAP'] = 'Site Karte';`

Also check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778499/add-language-name-in-url-by-using-routing-in-asp-net).